# How to suppress exit code of finished background jobs

Tags: bash, terminal, background-process

Is there a way to hide the exit code of the background jobs that have finished?

For example, if I run:

```
sleep 5&
```

After the 5s, if I hit return the terminal gives me:

```
[1]+  Done                    sleep 5
```

Is there a way to hide/suppress the last notification?

Particulary I have to do this:
nohup script >> file.txt &
And after that I don't want anything more on the terminal (stdout)

Comment: Have you tried just passing the stdout output to `/dev/null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ sleep 5 &
[1] 1234
$ disown
```

Comment: or: `sleep 5 & disown`

Answer (score 1):

A bigger hammer is to disable the "monitor mode" (job control) completely with [`set +m`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin):

Normally vs. monitor mode disabled:

```
$ sleep 1 & sleep 2
[1] 5247
[1]+  Done                    sleep 1

$ set +m
$ sleep 1 & sleep 2
[1] 5249
$
```

But then you can't pull background processes back to the foreground either:

```
$ set +m
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 5251
$ fg
-bash: fg: no job control
```