# How to hide asynchronous command completion result

Tags: bash

Is there any way to hide completion results for a command?

```
$ which sh &
[1] 86577
/bin/sh
[1]+  Done                    which sh # hide this
```

Comment: Yes. Working like  a searchengine: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225201/how-to-suppress-exit-code-of-finished-background-jobs , http://superuser.com/questions/305933/preventing-bash-from-displaying-done-when-a-background-command-finishes-execut